# Rails app thinks it's April 12 when it's actually April 11. How do I sync timezones?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I have a `Game` model. In `db/seeds` I am creating several game objects:

```
Game.create(id: 9, date: "2014-4-11 12am", time: "705PM", opponent: "Jacksonville", away: false, event: "friday night fireworks")
Game.create(id: 10, date: "2014-4-12 12am", time: "630PM", opponent: "Jacksonville", away: false, event: "grill giveaway")
```

Inside of a view I am looping through all the `@games` to see if game.date is equal to today's date.

```
<% games.each do |game| %>
  <% if ActiveSupport::TimeZone["Central Time (US & Canada)"].parse(game.date.to_s).utc.to_date.strftime("%_m/%d")[1..-1] == Time.zone.now.strftime("%_m/%d")[1..-1] && game.away == false %>
```

However, when I output

```
<%= ActiveSupport::TimeZone["Central Time (US & Canada)"].parse(game.date.to_s).utc.to_date.strftime("%_m/%d")[1..-1] %>
```

It returns "4/12". It skips the first Game in the seeds file, the one with the date of today, 4/11, and outputs the next Game with the date of 4/12.

At 7:00pm on 4/11:

```
Time.zone.now.strftime("%_m/%d")[1..-1]
```

outputs "4/12".

And

```
<%= ActiveSupport::TimeZone["Central Time (US & Canada)"].parse(game.date.to_s).utc.to_date.strftime("%_m/%d")[1..-1] %>
```

outputs "4/12"

The only thing I can think of is that the system thinks it's 4/12 somehow, which is why it's skipping over the first game with the date of 4/11?

I'm not sure how to match these up. And fyi, I put `config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'` inside `application.rb`

**EDIT**

Another development: in the rails console in terminal when I run `Time.zone.now` it returns `Fri, 11 Apr 2014 20:25:15 CDT -05:00`

But when I run `<%= Time.zone.now %>` inside my view in my application it outputs `2014-04-12 01:25:49 UTC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using `date` and `datetime` data types and leave out `time` - and like @mu is too short said don't append times onto your date values

Here is a blog post I wrote on rails and timezones: http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/

> Inside of a view I am looping through all the @games to see if game.date is equal to today's date.

try this instead:

```
<% Time.use_zone("Central Time (US & Canada)") do %>
  <% games.each do |game| %>
    <% if game.date == Date.current %>
      Game on! Today
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Again, please read the blog post (sample code as well). Set up your app with UTC as the default and change to other zones 'on demand' as needed (usually based on user settings).